# First "for loop" stops after first iteration python

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I am reading two different files with for loop. First "for loop" stops after first iteration. The print output is only line1 of f1 with all lines of f2 but then exit the loop.

```
for line1 in f1:
    line1 = line1.split('\t')
    for line2 in f2:
        line2 = line2.split('\t')

        print line1,line2
```

> **f1:**
>
> x1
>
> x2
>
> x3
>
> **f2:**
>
> y1
>
> y2
>
> y3
>
> **output:**
>
> x1 y1
>
> x1 y2
>
> x1 y3
>
> x2 y1
>
> x2 y2
>
> x2 y3
>
> x3 y1
>
> x3 y2
>
> x3 y3

Comment: Once you've read all of `f2` in the 1st iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop (and the `print`) won't execute again.

Comment: f1 and f2 are constructed in the same way ? I tested and the code works. Try just to test change f1 in the for loop to f2 and see if it iterates correctly.

Comment: @Johnny Mopp I think this might be the reason. Can you tell me how to continue this. I have tried "continue" but no change in output.

Comment: @farbiondriven I have tried both the ways. Still not working. :(

Comment: Sounds like you want to do something similar to `f2lines = [line for line in f2]` to create a list of the lines then iterate over that instead

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Question is edited.. please see it @LSelter

Comment: Have a look at Attempt 4, you were not resetting the cursor on file 2 once you got to the end of the file the first time round, unless you reopen the file in each iteration you must move the cursor to the beginning manually.

Comment: Thank.. I had look. But I am interested to know why after reading all f2 in the 1st iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop (and the print) won't execute again.

Comment: I just answered that, because the cursor is already at the end of f2, so there are no more lines to iterate over, hence the f2.seek(0) at the end of the outer look so that f2 can be read over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops are currently nested, which means that your program will read the entire contents of f2 for every line in f1. but once the end of file 2 is reached (at the end of the first outer look there are no more lines in  f2 to read. so we manually reset the cursor to the beginning.

Attempt 4:
You were not resetting the cursor on file 2 once you got to the end of the file the first time round, unless you reopen the file in each iteration you must move the cursor to the beginning manually.
If I have now understood you correctly:

```
def print_both(f1, f2):
    f1.seek(0)
    f2.seek(0)
    for line1 in f1:
        line1 = line1.split('\t')
        for line2 in f2:
            line2 = line2.split('\t')
            print(line1, line2)

        f2.seek(0)


print_both(open("f1.tsv", 'r'), open("f2.tsv", 'r'))
```

Comment: just printing all line from f1 and same number of lines from f2.

Comment: are you trying to read one , then the other or all lines from both of them even if one is finished?

Comment: Trying to read one , then the other or all lines from both of them even if one is finished

Comment: have a look at attempts 2 and 3 if any of them give you the behavior you are after

Comment: Thank for explanation @LSelter. I really appreciate your effort. I have checked Attemp4 and it is working fine.